# Does this seem like a solid encryption method?

Tags: vb.net

I found this code on a forum:

```
   Public Shared Sub Encryptor(wme As String, password As String)
            Try
                Dim key As Byte() = New Byte(31) {}
                Encoding.Default.GetBytes(password).CopyTo(key, 0)
                Dim aes As New RijndaelManaged() With
            {
                .Mode = CipherMode.CBC,
                .KeySize = 256,
                .BlockSize = 256,
                .Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros
            }
                Dim buffer As Byte() = File.ReadAllBytes(wme)
                Using matrizStream As New MemoryStream
                    Using cStream As New CryptoStream(matrizStream, aes.CreateEncryptor(key, key), CryptoStreamMode.Write)
                        cStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
                        Dim appendBuffer As Byte() = matrizStream.ToArray()
                        Dim finalBuffer As Byte() = New Byte(appendBuffer.Length - 1) {}
                        appendBuffer.CopyTo(finalBuffer, 0)
                        File.WriteAllBytes(wme, finalBuffer)
                    End Using
                End Using
                File.Move(wme, wme)
            Catch
            End Try
        End Sub
```

wme is the file path. Password is the password for the encryption. I was woundering if this was a strong encryption method or its some bad encryption method.

Comment: What's your objective here? What requirements do you have?

Comment: Is this aes? If it isn't were could I find an example of aes in vb.net?

Comment: [The documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aes(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) is a good place to start. If you need to ensure this code is secure then have whatever you do reviewed in a code audit by a qualified security professional before going live.

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  Your encryptor is overblown - you can wrap a filestream in the cryptostream and elide all the copy stuff

Comment: You are using a solid standard encryption method.  The real issue is the key and the parameters being used for the encryption.  Encrypting data and the letting people see the source for the encryption visible to the world is poor.  It is like putting the account name and password on a login page so anybody can get in.  You should hide as many encryption parameter in a configuration file so its not part of the source code making more difficult for anybody to see the parameters.  The more hidden parameter in an encryption method the harder it is for somebody to un-encrypt message.

Comment: If you "found this code on a forum" and do not understand it don't use it! You are responsible for all code you use and essentially take ownership of it in your use.

Comment: @jdweng The only thing that needs to be secret is the key. Security is not gained by obscuring the implementation. Security is solely obtained by the key and that must be kept secret from attackers. Further, the *solid standard encryption method* is flawed if AES as the OP seems to want AES because AES does not support a block size of 256.

Comment: Keep in mind that the most secure safe on the planet isn't secure if you write the combination on a sticky note and attach it to the door. Security isn't about security - it's about the lack of insecurity. Unless we could review the whole system we can't say if it's secure or not.

Comment: zaph : Security is based on the amount of time it takes to decrypt message not knowing the method or key.  The more combinations you need to try longer it takes to de-crypt the more secure the algorithm.  Now if an algorithm takes 100 year to de-crypt then adding more combinations really doesn't make it more secure.  But if you then buy a new computer that runs 1000 times faster then the time to de-crypt becomes 0.1 years.

Comment: @jdweng The consensus of cryptographic domain experts is that security is solely based on the key, not the method, hidden or not. In the case of AES, a 128-bit key it not subject to a brute force attack, even with a much, much, much faster computer.  If a try takes 1ns, and there are 128-bits it would take 10,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 years to try all combinations but the sun will only last another 5,000,000,000 years, a faster computer won't help.

Comment: Isn't that what I said.  I didn't get into specific times.  But if a key is stolen hiding the other parameter will still increase the time the hacker will take to break in.

Comment: @jdweng 1. Ah, 10,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 years is not enough security?  2. But no, the basic tenet is that the method does not need to be secret, indeed it is best made available, no false hopes based on obscurity. That is why the [Signal](https://signal.org) end-to-end encryption method and implementation is fully described and the code made available, it is arguably one of the top two secure message systems. Another example is HTTPS and TLS, fully described and code available.  3. If the attacker has the key all is lost, make no mistake that there is any security left.

Answer (score 1):

Rijndael with a BlockSize of 256-bits is **not AES**, AES only supports a block size if 128-bits. Not 31 bytes, there would be some unknown padding applied.

For AES use: `.BlockSize = 128`.

You need to supply an Initialization Vector (IV). The IV will also be the same as the block size, 128-bits (16-bytes), make it exactly that size. Use a random IV and prefix the encrypted data with it so it will be available for decryption.

Also AES supports three key sizes, 128, 192 and 256 bits, make the keys exactly the correct size.

Further, null padding is a bad idea and does not support binary data, instead the usual padding is PKCS#7 (sometimes specified as PKCS#5).